# How to populate data from ms access to vb.net combobox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I was looking codes online on how to populate data from ms access to combobox, I used all the codes I found but none of those works. I really need help on how to do it right. This was one of the codes I have used.

```
MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    MyConn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = MyConn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT [Worker Name] from OVRL_REPORTS"

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        cbx_wname.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
    End While
    dr.Close()
```

cbx_wname is the name of my combobox.

Comment: `I used all the codes I found but none of those works` ***would you care to elaborate on this***? For example: are there any errors? Did you set a breakpoint on `MyConn.Open()` and if so what happens, did it open or did it throw an exception?...

Comment: There were no errors but the combobox is empty.

Comment: Did you set breakpoints and step into the code?

Comment: Where is that code located?  If it's in the `Load` event handler then one possible explanation for an empty `ComboBox` is that an exception was thrown.  If a 64-bit application throws an exception in the `Load` event handler then the exception is swallowed and the app just carries on without notification or executing the rest of the code in that event handler. The suggested debugging would reveal whether that is the case or not. So would an exception handler.

Comment: Yes sir @jmcilhinney I put the codes on the load event. So what should I do? Where should I put the code? Do the codes above is fine?

Comment: @zaggler I don't know what is that breakpoint and where to put it. I am really beginner. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: I recommend reading/watching a tutorial about debugging like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A)

Comment: The code is in the right place but it is not fine.  It is throwing an exception.  You need to find out what that exception is, find out what's causing it and then fix it.  It could be an incorrect connection string or an issue with your SQL or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have just commented and said `Have a look into the command 'OleDbDataAdapter'` but as I need more Reputation to comment I'll just put what I've managed to get to work as an answer, hopefully it will help you.

Also I'm fairly new myself and when I tried using the normal DataReader to get values from Access into a Combobox I couldn't get it to work either.

The below is the 'jist' of one of my first working Combobox's that was filled from Access using `OleDbDataAdapter`, with your field/table names applied.

```
    ' DataSet for Storing the return values from Access
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet()

    ' Command for Getting values from Access
    Dim Command As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Worker Name] FROM [OVRL_REPORTS]", myconnection)

    ' Open Connection
    myconnection.Open()

    ' Fill DataSet with Return Values from Access
    Command.Fill(dsDoctype, "Worker Name")

    ' Set DisplayMember and DataSource to values Stored in DataSet
    With cbx_wname
        .DisplayMember = "Worker Name"
        .DataSource = DataSet.Tables("Worker Name")
    End With

    myconnection.Close()
```

I would post exactly how I get around filling comboboxs currently but the whole process is split amongst several functions.

This website is what I used as a basis to get Comboboxes to work - [homeandlearn - Data Sets and Data Adapters](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p5.html) hopefully it can help you too.